# how to take all array elements except last element in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array like this.

`string[] queries` with data more than one string.

I want to skip the last string from the element and take the remaining. I have come up with

```
var remStrings = queries.Reverse().Skip(1).Take(queries.Length - 1);
```

Is there a better alternative to this?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
var remStrings = queries.Take(queries.Length - 1);
```

No need to Reverse and Skip. Just take one less element than there are in the array.

If you really wanted the elements in the reverse order, you could tack on a `.Reverse()` to the end.

Comment: string array doesn't have a `Take()` method. What am I missing?

Comment: @TMC - Take() is an extension method for IEnumerable. You need to include LINQ.

Comment: In case you want to store the resulting array in the same variable and not in var: `fileData = fileData.Take(fileData.Length - 1).ToArray();`

Answer (score 49):

For anyone finding this now...

With the upcoming support for ranges and indices C# 8 and .NET Core 3.0 you can simply write

```
var remStrings = queries[..^1]
```

This is short for

```
var remStrings = queries[0..^1]
```

This works by converting the `0` and `1` to indices (`System.Index`), with the `^` being the marker (actually an operator) to index from the end of a sequence. From these indices a range (`System.Range`) is then generates which can then be used to access the array. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

Currently this only works in the preview version of .NET Core 3.0

Answer (score 15):

Microsoft's Reactive Extensions' Team has the Interactive Extensions (NuGet "System.Interactive") that lets you do this:

```
var remStrings = queries.SkipLast(1);
```

Answer (score 12):

Why not just have:

```
var remStrings = queries.Take(queries.Length-1);
```

Which will return them in the same order.

Append `.Reverse()` to swap the order if that's a necessary requirement:

```
var remStrings = queries.Take(queries.Length-1).Reverse();
```

Answer (score 2):

[This answer from a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4166561/541420) is also worth mentioning as it elegantly applies to any `IEnumerable` in a single pass, without the need to know its number of elements beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
You could effectively replace your array with the same array minus the last element with the following line or code:

```
queries = queries.Take(queries.Length - 1).ToArray();
```

If you would like to create a method that does this for you, then you could use the following:

```
public static string[] TrimLastElement(string[] arr) {
    return arr.Take(arr.Length - 1).ToArray();
}
```

And implement it in your code like so:

```
queries = TrimLastElement(queries);
```

Comment: There are no variables of type `var`. `var` is just a keyword that instructs the compiler to infer the type. Your line of code is identical to `var temp = temp.Take(temp.Length - 1).ToArray<string>();`.

Comment: I understand what you wanna say, it should be like    `temp = temp.Take(temp.Length - 1).ToArray();`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! My post has now been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an indirect solution. However, a different approach without using extension.

```
// Convert string array to generic list
List<string> queries = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" }.ToList();

var lastElement = queries.LastOrDefault();
var takeAllExceptLastElement = queries.Take(queries.LastIndexOf(lastElement));
        
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", takeAllExceptLastElement));
```