# C# - string[] does not contain a definition for 'SkipLast' and no accessible extension method

Tags: c#

.NET Framework 4.7.2.  Visual Studio 2019.  This issue is not specifically addressed in other posts about this error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stuff
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         string firstPart = "ABC 123 XYZ";
         string firstPartMinusLast = string.Join(" ", firstPart.Split(' ').SkipLast(1));
         Console.WriteLine(firstPartMinusLast);
        }
    }
}
```

I get an Intellisense error on `SkipLast`:

> string[] does not contain a definition for 'SkipLast' and no
> accessible extension method 'SkipLast' accepting a first argument of
> type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)

Per any documentation I can find online, `using System.Linq` is supposed to cover this method?

Comment: `SkipLast()` is part of .NET Core, but not .NET Framework.

Comment: [SkipLast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast) seems to be new in NetStandard 2.1. It didn't exists in Net Framework 4.7.

Comment: @Sach SkipLast is a method of `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>` and Arrays implements that interface

Comment: Ahhh I see.  So to achieve `SkipLast` in .NET Framework, will I need to do some sort of calculation on count of strings generated by `Split` and then `Join` all but the highest number?  Seems terribly inefficient.

Comment: @Stpete111 You could do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3264855/2188407)

Comment: Yes I do believe `Take` is where I need to focus.  Thanks @JustinLessard !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check the purple box at the top of the `Enumerable.SkipLast` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast?view=netcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7.2), you'll see that it is not available in .NET Framework 4.7.2

---

For what it's worth, the source code is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Skip.cs), so you can just add it yourself. The logic is brilliant:

- On the first call to the enumerator, `count` items are taken from `source` and added to a queue, then one is dequeued and returned.
- On subsequent calls, the next item is added to the queue, and if that wasn't the last item in `source`, an item is dequeued and returned.
- When it's done, the queue contains a cache of the last items in the `source` (which we wanted to skip), and it was done without knowing ahead of time how many items `source` contained.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<T>();

        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                if (queue.Count == count)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        yield return queue.Dequeue();
                        queue.Enqueue(e.Current);
                    } while (e.MoveNext());
                }
                else
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(e.Current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```